# Max offset from a variant column (JSON) while using lateral flatten function

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

I have a table with two variant data type columns (Record_Key, Record_Content). "Record_Key" column contains "Key_ID" and "Offset" in a JSON format and "Record_Content" also contains the actual JSON message/transaction/Payload.

Any ideas on how can I select Max "offset" records from "Record_Key" column while also flattening the data in the above mentioned columns using lateral_flatten function?

Can I use a subquery to select max offset? or should I use CTE to 1st flatten the data and then so max select?

Comment: given a sub-query is a CTE (albeit one that can only be used once). I better question is are you want to get the 'other values" from the `record_content` that match the `max(key_id)` of the first, and are they some other field you are partitioning the data other?

Comment: Yes, I do want to get the "other values" from record_content based on max(offset_id) grouped on key_id. There are no other fields used for partitioning except for key_id and offset_id

Comment: Can you show us some sample data and desired result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

given a sub-query is a CTE (albeit one that can only be used once). that aspect dose not super matter.

so if your data looks like:

```
SELECT
parse_json('{"Key_ID":"a", "Offset":0}') AS Record_Key
parse_json('{"val_a":"a_a0", "val_b":"b_a0"}') AS Record_Content
SELECT
parse_json('{"Key_ID":"b", "Offset":2}') AS Record_Key
parse_json('{"val_a":"a_b2", "val_b":"b_b2"}') AS Record_Content
SELECT
parse_json('{"Key_ID":"c", "Offset":4}') AS Record_Key
parse_json('{"val_a":"a_c4", "val_b":"b_c4"}') AS Record_Content
```

thus from this data you want to get:

```
key_id, Offset, val_a, val_b
c,      4,      a_c4,  b_c4
```

because offset 4 is the biggest. (this is a multi-row example, if your data is array inside the `Record_Key` you can FLATTEN that)

```
SELECT 
    Record_Key:Key_ID::text as Key_ID
    Record_Key:Offset::number as Offset
    Record_Content:val_a::text as val_a
    Record_Content:val_b::text as val_b
FROM table
QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Key_ID ORDER BY Offset DESC) = 1
```

so this will pull all the rows out of the JSON and only keep the per `Key_ID`

If the shape of your Data is different the first step is to get the data you want and then filter out the data you don't want via something like a [QUALIFY](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/constructs/qualify.html)